# sort numbers according to last number in line

Tags: linux, sort

the following is file example

```
585.3 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1732 pcv DC month 202204 day 20220413
585.5 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1734 pcv DC month 202204 day 20220413
585.8 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1733 pcv DC month 202204 day 20220413
585.9 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1731 pcv DC month 202203 day 20220304
586.1 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1732 pcv DC month 202203 day 20220304
586.5 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1735 pcv DC month 202204 day 20220413
587.1 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1734 pcv DC month 202203 day 20220304
587.3 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1733 pcv DC month 202203 day 20220304
587.4 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1736 pcv DC month 202204 day 20220413
587.4 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1737 pcv DC month 202204 day 20220413
587.7 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1738 pcv DC month 202204 day 20220413
588.0 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1735 pcv DC month 202203 day 20220304
594.3 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1730 pcv DC month 202205 day 20220515
594.3 M   netG ple jdhe jdhe_daily se 1737 pcv DC month 202203 day 20220303
```

we want to sort the date on the last field from old date to new date

dose `sort` command support to sort numbers according to last field?

Comment: No, you cannot define 'the last field' with `sort`. Only if you know the fields number, if it's always 14 fields, you can use `-k14`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -k 14b,14 file
```

sort by the 14th column

Comment: Note that `sort -k14` defines one `sort` key that start with the 14th field (fields being delimited by default by the transition between a non-blank and a blank) and ends at the end of the line. To *sort by the 14th column*, you'd need `sort -k 14b,14` with key here starting with the 14th field, leading blanks trimmed and ending with the 14th field.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, thanks I will edit the answer.